# Reading 2D array from a file and passing it to another function

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I wrote down this code in C++ to read a 2D array from a file. Now I'd like to organize better my code with functions. The issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to pass the 2D array I loaded to memory to another function in the same program.
This is the code I need to organize into functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define M 4
#define N 4

int main(){
    int i, j;
    float A[M][N];
    string line;
    ifstream matrix("matrix.txt");
    if (matrix.is_open())
    {
        do
        {
            for(i=0; i<M; i++) 
            {
                for(j=0; j<N; j++) 
                    matrix >> A[i][j];
            }
        }
        while (getline(matrix,line));
        matrix.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    float sumline[M]={0};                       

    for(i=0;i<M;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
            sumline[i]+=A[i][j];            
    }

    float sumcolumn[N]={0};                     

    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<M;i++)
            sumcolumn[j]+=A[i][j];      
    }


    for (i=0; i<M; i++){                    
        for (j=0; j<N; j++){                
            if(sumline[i]<sumcolumn[j]){    
                cout << "Error, total sum of column "<<j<<" is greater than the sum of the line"<<i<<endl;
                return 0;                   
            }
        }
    }

    int mincol=sumcolumn[0];                

    for (i=0; i<N; i++){                    
        if(mincol>sumcolumn[i])
            mincol==sumcolumn[i];
    }
    float avgline = 0.0;
    for (i=0; i<M; i++){
        avgline=avgline+sumline[i];
    }
    avgline = avgline/M;

    if (avgline * 3 > mincol) {
        cout << "Conditions verified"<<endl;
        }
    else{
        cout << "Error, triple of the avg of line is less than the lowest sum of column"<<endl;
        return 0;       
        }

    return 0;
}
```

The code basically does some math on the 2D array. I'd also like to keep as simple as possible so even if `using namespace std;` it's not really good practice or the way I'm reading the array from the file is really basic I need it to be like that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems you want a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)?

Comment: And as a hint on solving the problem of passing the matrices to functions easily, consider using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of C-style arrays.

Comment: The code I wrote down works as intended. I wanted to give the full picture of what I need to do and on what kind of code I'm working on.
I'll take a look the standard array function and get back to you if I have more questions. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: So, I've been looking at this function and it's a more C++ way to work with an array. But still the question that I can't answer is this one basically: I'm building the 2D array reading from a file so I'm passing all the values in the same function. Now what kind of function should I have to ```return``` the 2D array? It can't just be a ```float``` function. The only things I can think of is passing the array values from  ```main()``` but that's not how it should be I think.

Comment: Using the type-alias from [the answer by darune](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56848137/440558), just have the return type be `MyArrayType`?

Comment: ```void matrix_load()
{
  int i,j;
  using MyArrayType = <std::array<std::array<float>, M>, N>;
  MyArrayType A;
  string line;
  ifstream matrix("matrix.txt");
  if (MyArrayType.is_open())
  {
    do
    {
      for (i=0; i<M; i++)
      {
        for (j=0; j<N; j++)
        matrix >> A[i][j]
      }
    }
    while (getline(matrix,line));
    MyArrayType.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  return MyArrayType;
}

void sudofunction (MyArrayType&)
{
  //more math here
}```
With all correct declarations this doesen't work. Array expected identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using c-array

```
float A[M][N];
```

*You may instead use*

```
using MyArrayType = std::array<std::array<float>, M>, N>;
MyArrayType A;
```

Now you can pass by reference (`MyArrayType&` or `const MyArrayType&`  )

That being said: a c array can be passed as with the more difficult syntax: `(float (&a)[M][N]);` - it is strongly recommended to use `std::array` instead where possible.

Comment: So that way I don't need to ```return``` any value and the function type is ```void```. And I only need to pass the array as input to the other functions, right?

Comment: Also, instead of `#define M 4` the 'C++ Way' would be a constexpr. And instead of OP's 'sumcolumn', how aboot using standard library functions like std::accumulate or so? Although this isn't Python, i bet that code can be made clearer + compressed to 10% its size.

Comment: @nada Yeah, I really think it can be optimized but, for now, I don't have much time to work on perfecting my C++ knowledge unfortunately. The work I'm doing, for now, is just gathering tools for a job, no matter if they're not efficient. Programming is not my strong suit for now. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @darune. Not that I would ever use plain arrays in C++. But OP asked how to pass a 2d-array. You can do by reference or by pointer using the following syntax: "void function (float (&a)[M][N]);" or "void function (float(*a)[M][N]);" and then call it with "function(A);" or "function(&A);". That is the correct answer. And the very strong recommendation is: Do never ever use plain arrays in C++